# nodejs pdf parse getting value after specific string

Tags: node.js, pdfparser, pdf2json

my goal is to get a certain string after a predefined text. In this case i would like to read the following value:
[image: required value]

I found out this is possible using regex, therefore i tried this:

```
 const fs = require("fs");
 const PDFParser = require("pdf2json");

 // Get all the filenames from the patients folder
 const files = fs.readdirSync("templates");

 // All of the parse patients
 let patients = [];

// Make a IIFE so we can run asynchronous code
(async () => {

// Await all of the patients to be passed
// For each file in the patients folder
await Promise.all(files.map(async (file) => {

    // Set up the pdf parser
    let pdfParser = new PDFParser(this, 1);

    // Load the pdf document
    pdfParser.loadPDF(`templates/${file}`);

    // Parsed the patient
    let patient = await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

        // On data ready
        pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", (pdfData) => {

            // The raw PDF data in text form
            const raw = pdfParser.getRawTextContent().replace(/\r\n/g, " ");

            // Return the parsed data
            
            resolve({
                gesamtbetrag: /Amount\s(:*?)--/i.exec(raw)[1].trim()
            });

        });

    });

    // Add the patient to the patients array
    patients.push(patient);

}));

// Save the extracted information to a json file
fs.writeFileSync("patients.json", JSON.stringify(patients));

 })();
```

I'm getting the error that my array is at position 1 null:

> Cannot read property '1' of null

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `exec` method returns the first match as an array, or null if there is no match.

Your pattern  `/Amount\s(:*?)--/i` is searching for the word `Amount` followed by a whitespace followed by zero or more `:` colons followed by `--`.

There is no match, so `exec` returns `null`, and the `[1]` array index fails.

Try `console.log(/Amount\s(:*?)--/i.exec(raw))` and make sure it returns an array, and not null. Tweak your RegEx until it matches.

`console.log(raw)` will show you the text you are dealing with, and tools like RegexBuddy will let you debug your RegEx.